# php script getting called from a html

Tags: php, html

I want to create a HTML file.
I want that HTML file to take some input variables and call a php script?

can you please help me with a snipp of this? or any url that has this as a simple example.

I have a HTML file, when the I click "next", I want to call the php script.
That php script the page it is in (say 5th page) so when I click "next", it should take the $currpage=5 (variable) and send it to the php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a FORM in your HTML and add some INPUT elements with a SUBMIT button. The "action" attribute of the form should contain the path for your PHP script on a server configured to run PHP. Check out this very basic tutorial from [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php)

Comment: is it mandatory that I should use a form to do this? for my requirement is :I have a HTML file, when the I click "next", I want to call the php script. That php script the page it is in (say 5th page) so when I click "next", it should take the $currpage=5 (variable) and send it to the php script

Comment: To my understanding, you are mixing up server-side and client-side languages. Firstly, all PHP processing occurs on the server and the ways to send data from a HTML from to a PHP server is either by using a FORM action with get/post method, or generating a URL to the PHP script with your data as GET parameters or via an AJAX call which I don't see is required in your situation.

Comment: I am not looking at AJAX.  >generating a URL to the PHP script with your data as GET parameters ..I am looking at this .can you helpme how I can send data without the form. I want to call the php script on my server with one input variable from my htmkl

Comment: if your PHP script is looking for a GET parameter with name currpage, then add a hyperlink to the "next" in your page with href as "/path/to/your/file.php?currpage=5".

Comment: can you please give me an example, how to send 2 values like this:/path/to/your/file.php?currpage=5 and also how to use to GETthem\

Comment: You can send multiple name=value pairs by separating them with '&'. So, it goes like this: "/path/to/your/file.php?currpage=5&prevpage=4&nextpage=6". On the PHP end, you should use the global array GET to access these. In this case, $currpage=$_GET['currpage']; $prevpage= $_GET['prevpage'] etc. I suggest you go through a beginner PHP tutorial from Tizag pr w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

See the official PHP tutorial (specifically "Your first PHP-enabled page" and "Dealing with Forms") for all you're wanting to do here:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 1):

This is utterly bog-standard beginning PHP/HTML, and you could've found it anywhere on the web if you'd just googled for "PHP introduction"

html file:

```
<html>

<body>

<form method="post" action="yourscript.php">
<input type="text" name="mytextfield">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
    echo "You entered: ", $_POST['mytextfield'];
```